# How to know if a class is from the JRE or from an external Jar?

Tags: java, introspection

Does anybody knows if it's possible (is there a library) to know if a `Class<?>` variable is included in the JRE or not ?

Here is what I would want :

```java
Class<String> stringClass = String.class;
System.out.println(TheMagickLibrary.isJREClass(stringClass)); // should display true

Class<AnyClass> anotherClass = AnyClass.class;
System.out.println(TheMagickLibrary.isJREClass(anotherClass)); // should display false
```

Comment: Why do you need to know this at runtime?

Comment: try String isJREClass(Class cl) {return cl.getClassloader().toString();}

Comment: I need it for an Arquillian test : I want to discover all the classes used by a class automatically in order to add them to the Test `Archive<?>`. But if it's a JRE one, it's not necessary, so I want to detect it...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I can offer you 2 solutions.

1. Get class package and check whether it starts with `java.`, `sun.`, `com.sun.`
2. Get the class' class loader:

> ```
> Returns the class loader for the class.  Some implementations may use
> null to represent the bootstrap class loader. This method will return
> null in such implementations if this class was loaded by the bootstrap
> class loader.
> ```

As you can see they say "some implmentations may return null". It means that for these implementations `clazz.getClassLoader() == null` means that the class is loaded by bootstrap class loader and therefore belongs to JRE. BTW this works on my system (Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_30-b12)).

If not check the documentation of `ClassLoader#getParent()`:

> ```
>  Returns the parent class loader for delegation. Some implementations may
>  use <tt>null</tt> to represent the bootstrap class loader. This method
>  will return <tt>null</tt> in such implementations if this class loader's
>  parent is the bootstrap class loader.
> ```

Again, some implementations will return null if current class loader is a bootstrap.

Finally I'd recommend the following strategy:

```
public static boolean isJreClass(Class<?> clazz) {
    ClassLoader cl = clazz.getClassLoader();
    if (cl == null || cl.getParent() == null) {
        return true;
    }
    String pkg = clazz.getPackage().getName();
    return pkg.startsWith("java.") || pkg.startsWith("com.sun") || pkg.startsWith("sun."); 
}
```

I believe this is good enough for 99% of cases.

Comment: I tested the first solution at first, but then I realized some external jars have classes in `sun.` or `java.`, and others in `javax.` (`javax.swing` especially) are part of the JRE... well it's not a solid solution. I'll try the `getClassLoader()` one.

Comment: OK, it seems to work, thanks ! I also tryed `clazz.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource()` as indicated [here](http://www.exampledepot.com/egs/java.lang/ClassOrigin.html) and also seemed to work (but less clear on the documentation)

Comment: I think that getProtectionDomain() is the right solution. Thank for your comment.

Comment: Why are you thinking that @AlexR ? The Javadoc for `getCodeSource()` is just "`Returns the CodeSource of this domain which may be null`", nothing about the parent bootstrap loader...